# geopandas.sjoin : Does the size of the polygon matters?

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, geodataframe, predicates

I am doing a spatial join with `geopandas` as follows:

```
joinIlots = gpd.sjoin(left_df=Area, right_df=data,  how="left", predicate="intersects")
```

The geodataframe `data` represents transactions with a geometry that is joined (`left join`)  with the geodataframe `Area`. The polygons of the geodataframe `Area` are as follows:

```
image 1
```

[image]

As shown in the image, the polygons are big and the `left join` managed to match a lot of data in their respective locations. For example in the red polygon i do match 120 transactions.

However, the results can be different when working with the blue polygons below (`image 2`). `image 2` represents the same map (`image 1`) but shown in smaller polygons (each block represent a block of houses).

```
image 2
```

[image]

When we `left join` the same transactions (`data`), the results are different. I only manage to match 25 transactions as opposed to 120 transactions in `image 1`.

Whats the best approach to capture the maximum transactions in the `left join` for `image 2`? Clearly some transactions are being lost when working with smaller polygons.

Comment: `data` contains point geometries? Could it be that the points are on the roads?

Comment: `data` contains small polygons. It is possible some transactions hit the roads but very unlikely. Iam thinking of using either `df.geometry.buffer` or `df.geometry.scale` to increase the borders of the small polygons and hopefully fix the problem but i am not sure by how much I should increase the buffer. `df.geometry.scale` is more explicit

Comment: @alphabetasoup  can I allocate the polygons of `data` (or the centoird of the polygons) to the closest polygon in `Area`. This would avoid the problem I am currently having no? Which function would be most appropriate?  would this function be appropriate `geopandas.sjoin_nearest` ?

Comment: I tried `geopandas.sjoin_nearest` and i found this tool to be dangerous for my case as it pulls for every row in `Area` all nearest transactions (in `data`) at the desired `max_distance`. Code is: `gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=Area, right_df=data, how='left',max_distance=1, distance_col = "distances")`. To achieve this result I first converted my `crs` to meter `Area.to_crs(26191)` and `data.to_crs(26191)` and I chose a max_distance of 1 meter . I am getting a geodataframe of more than 1 million rows which seems a lot (in `gpd.sjoin` i only get 52K rows). whats wrong?